# AS3 Adobe Air stop execution of code

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I'm developing app using flash pfofessional CC for iOS and android using air sdk 15.
Is their any way to stop the execution of the code, is their any function to do this, 
like

```
pause(for_seconds);
```

Comment: Please [Read the Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) either use the `Timer` class, or work with the `setTimeout` function (not recommended).

Comment: no way to stop the code execution, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a sleep function, but you can delay the call of a function:

```
function delayedFunctionCall(delay:int) {
    trace('going to execute the function you passed me in', delay, 'milliseconds');
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(delay, 1);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, launch);
    timer.start();
}

function launch(e:TimerEvent):void{
  timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, launch);
  yourFunction(); // <----
}
```

You can try with this too:

```
var timeToWait:int=100;
startTime = getTimer();
while(getTimer() - startTime < timeToWait){}
```